# improving speed of nested python for-loops which append lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, memory, append

Inside my nested for-loops I am doing some calculations which are appended to lists. In some cases the for-loops will be huge generating lists that are hundreds of millions and even billions of entries. When the lists gets huge it seems to fill up memory slow things down.

Anyone having suggestions for how I can execute the below quicker? Alternative ways to set it up which doesn't drain memory?

```
n = 10000 #This number can be much higher
m = 10000 #This number can be much higher
x = []
y = []
a = 1
for n in range(n):
    b = 1
    for m in range(m):
        x.append(a+b) 
        y.append(a+b*2)
    b = b+1
a = a+1
```

Comment: It all depends on what you actually need the finished product to be. You might not need to be generating huge lists but maybe you do, we don't know your use case for this. But if you really want to write optimal code, especially code that loops, Python is a terrible choice for that unless you're using, like Cython.

Comment: Or something like - https://numba.pydata.org/   as ^^^ pointed out.  *"Just apply one of the Numba decorators to your Python function, and Numba does the rest.*

Comment: Thanks, will try out your suggestions.

Comment: It ran 7 times faster with Numba!